# Stuck on this question based on work

Tags: algebra-precalculus

A man's basic pay for a 40 hour-week is Rs. 20. Overtime is paid for at 25% above the basic rate. In a certain week, he worked overtime and his total wage was Rs. 25. He, therefore, worked for

a. 45 hrs b. 48 hrs c. 47 hrs d. 50 hrs e. 41 hrs

Man works for 40 hour-week in Rs. 20
Then his rate of doing work will be 50 paise per hour
Since, he is paid 25% above the basic rate, hence $1.25*50= 6.25 paise per hour= Rs. 5/8 per hour$
Rs. $5/8$ is paid for one hour
Then Rs 1 will be paid for $8/5$ hours
And Rs. 25 will be paid for $8/5*25=40$ hours
But the answer is 48 hours in which they have added overtime work hours
Can anyone help me with how to calculate the overtime work hours?

Answer (score 3):

If overtime is paid at $125\%$ the normal rate, and the normal week is paid at Rs. $0.5$ each hour, then overtime must be paid at Rs. $0.5*1.25=0.625$. Since his total wage was Rs. $25$, then he earned Rs. $5$ by working overtime, and if $h$ is the number of overtime hours, then
$$0.625h=5$$
$$h=8$$
So he worked a total of $48$ hours.

Comment: How he earned Rs. 5 by working overtime? @Nilknarf

Comment: If he earns $20$ by working the $40$-hour week, then the extra $\$5$ must be from overtime.

Comment: Thanks, you made it look so easy @Nilknarf